# Detecting value change in any case, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want after click on button and change input value, result alert 'Ok Done' but doesn't work it.The value may be numbers and letters.

```js
$("#myTextBox").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
    alert('Ok Done');
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
    //alert('ok');
    $("#myTextBox").val(
        function(i, val) {
            return val * 1 + 1
        }
    );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="myTextBox" type="text" value="1"/>
<button> Click me and chenge input value </button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aLrLq2gt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` does not trigger `change` event, you need to call `.change()` or `.keyup()` to trigger the event

```js
$("#myTextBox").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
        alert('Ok Done');
    });

    $('button').on('click', function() {
        //alert('ok');
        $("#myTextBox").val(
            function(i, val) {
                return val * 1 + 1
            }
        ).change();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myTextBox" type="text" value="1"/>


<button>
Click me and chenge input value
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.on("input", function()` or `.bind("input", function() {` this will include all input formats including paste, keyup, keypress, change.

Comment: I did it, but it does not work.Please tell me an example, here: https://jsfiddle.net/aLrLq2gt/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myTextBox").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
        alert('Ok Done');
    });
```

works just fine. Just introduce the change event on the input.
Here is the working plunker for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/stmVc2xZnyg6fGLc8qcc?p=preview

and working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rumba_alex47/pvfewas1/